# When i am trying to System.out.println

Tags: java

I have created a program for a homework project which allows me to enter all the data once run EG: first name etc etc.  So my public class is as follows below

```
public Borrower(String fName, String lName, String lNumber, int numberOfBooks,
        String street, String town, String postcode) {  
  firstName = fName;  
  lastName = lName;  
  libraryNumber = lNumber;  
  noOfBooks = numberOfBooks;   
  address = new Address(street, town, postcode);  
}
```

I then have a section such as:

```
public void printBorrowerDetails() {  
  System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName+ "\n" + "\n" +"Library Number: " 
      + libraryNumber +  "\n" +"Number of loans: " + noOfBooks);  
}
```

How can I write it so `Address` will print in this format

```
FirstName SecondName  
street  
town  
postcode
```

The code for the address class is inside another class that has been linked, the code is

```
public class Address {

    private String postcode;
    private String street;
    private String town;

    public Address (String street, String town, String postcode)
    { 
        this.street= street;
        this.town= town;
        this.postcode= postcode;
    }

    public String getFullAddress()
    {
        return street+"\n"+town+"\n"+postcode;
    }

    public String getPostcode()
    {
        return postcode;
    }

    public String getStreet()
    {
        return street;
    }

    public String getTown()
    {
        return town;
    }

    public void printAddress()
    {
        System.out.println(street+"\n"+town+"\n"+postcode);

    }

    public void setFullAddress(String street, String town, String postcode)
    {
        street= street;
        town= town;
        postcode= postcode;
    }

    public void setPostcode(String postcode)
    { 
        this.postcode= postcode;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street)
    {
        this.street= street;
    }

    public void setTown(String town)
    {
        this.town= town;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for Address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have getter methods for Address' street, town, and postcode as well as a private variable for address, there are two ways of achieving this:

```
System.out.println(address.getStreet() + "\n" + address.getTown() + "\n" + getPostcode());
```

or

```
System.out.println(address.getStreet());
System.out.println(address.getTown());
System.out.println(address.getPostcode());
```

Also, if you're going to print out just Address's detail, you should try to keep it to be just the address rather than including the borrower for the sake of good practice. If you really want to print out the `FirstName` and `LastName`, you would need to pass those values to the `Address` constructors but it no longer is *just* `Address`.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print(FirstName + " " + SecondName + "\n");
System.out.println(street + "\n" + town + "\n" + postcode);
```

you have to use print function instead of println to do this job...

Comment: In Java, you concatenate string through '+', not '.'

Comment: i am sorry for that.. :)

Comment: no buddy knows everything but, everybody knows something.. :) keep smiling.

Comment: You know that you can edit you answer to correct problems, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MessageFormat class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) from the Java API. For example:

```
String result = MessageFormat.format(
    "{0} {1} \n {2} \n {3} \n {4}",
    borrower.firstName, Borrower.secondName, address.street, address.town, address.postcode);
```

Use your getter methods for the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(address.getStreet());
System.out.println(address.getTown());
System.out.println(address.getPostcode());
```

Comment: thanks guys i was puzzled for hours and all i was missing was the end ());

Comment: Consider adding some text to your code to explain what you have done/how and why it solved the problem. This way your answer is a lot more useful for future readers

Answer (score 0):

```
    private streetname;
    private townname;
    private postnumber;
    public void address(string street,string town,int postcode){
         streetname=street;
         townname=town;
         postnumber=post;
 System.out.println(streetname +"\n"+ townname  +"\n"+ postnumber);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is call the toString() method to your Address class. toString is actually a method every object uses (part of the Object superclass iirc), and it is automatically called whenever you try to print an object using System.out.print. However, **by default, this method returns a hashcode**, which we don't want in your case. Because of this, you must override the default by adding a new toString method to your object class, like so.

```
public class Address{
    .
    .
    .
    public String toString(){
        return street + "\n" + town + "\n" + postcode;
    }
}
```

Then when you use

```
System.out.println(address);
```

it will print as specified in your object's toString() method.
You can also write it as

```
System.out.println(address.toString());
```

though like I said, this isn't really necessary because java knows to call the toString() method.

toString() can be a real time saver and reduces clutter when you have more than one of an object to print.

-edit-

It's worth pointing out that you can also do this for your Borrower class.

```
public class Borrower{
     .
     .
     .
     public String toString(){
          return fName + " " + lName + "\n\nLibrary Number: " + libraryNumber
        + "\nNumber Of Loans: " + noOfBooks + "\n" + address;
     }
}
```

Then in your main code, just put... (For the sake of demonstration, let's assume you called your Borrower "borrower")

```
System.out.println(borrower);
```